# Prove that $n! = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}d_k,$ where $d_n$ is the number of derangements of ${1,2,..., n}$.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, derangements

Prove that
$$n! = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}d_k,$$
where $d_n$ is the number of derangements of ${1,2,..., n}$.
We know that the number of derangements $d_n$ is given by
$$d_n=n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
Thus we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
We take note that
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Let $x=-1$ and we see that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}n!$$
This is the only way I could think of to simplify the expression, but I do not think it is useful in this proof. Any help would be great!

Comment: Note $e^x$ series has sum to $\infty$ not $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** Try a combinatorial proof, much easier : a permutation is determined by the choice of its $n-k$ fixed points and the fact that the other $k$ elements are "deranged".